# Proving that uncountable matrix multiplication is associative

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have been looking for uncountable large structures that generalize the idea of matrix multiplication and noticed the following pattern

Given functions $M_1(x,y) , M_2(x,y)$ defined on the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$  one can define their "matrix product" as

$$ M_3(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1} M_1 (s, y) M_2 (x, 1-s) ds  = ( M_1 M_2 )$$

If we try to approximate this integral with riemann sums, we find that the approximations are computationally equivalent to multiplying ever higher order matrices (to produce a third matrix), but it's not clear that associativity is preserved as we take the limit to forming an integral.

### My work:

for 3 functions A,B,C I expressed  $A(BC)$ and $(AB)C$ in terms of nested integrals but now am not clear on how to show that the 2 expressions are equal. One idea was to perturb the definition above to: $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} M_1 (s, y) M_2 (x, -s) ds$ and then to show associativity for this simpler looking operation, [it then is easy  to show that maps sending the open unit square to the whole plane, composed with this operation, and then said map's inverse is equivalent to the earlier operation]

Comment: I think you could follow the same formal approach as showing matrix multiplication is associative, but use fubinis theorem when you need to switch the order of integrals (instead of sums)

Comment: Formal matrix multiplication I prove by showing 2x2 matrix multiplication is associative. Then use induction to show that $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix multiplication is associative for all finite $n$.. Then show that general $k\times k$ matrix multiplication can embed into $2^{\lceil \log k \rceil } \times 2^{\lceil \log k \rceil }$ multiplication.

Comment: The countable structure to induct on here is what I lack. And some argument showing that convergent Riemann sums of $A(BC)$ and $(AB)C$ are equivalent feels too tedious to do.

Comment: It might also work to view $M_1$ as defining a linear operator $C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$, $f \mapsto \left(y \mapsto \int_0^1 M_1(t, y) f(1-t) \, dt\right)$ and then show that this matrix multiplication corresponds to composition.  Then it would remain to show this mapping of "matrices" to linear operators is injective.  (Of course, to fully reproduce the usual argument along these lines from the finite case, we might need to extend the domain of the linear operators to include distributions like $\delta(x - x_0)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B,C:[0,1]^2\to \mathbb R$ be matrices.
$$
\begin{align}
((AB)C)(x,y) 
&= \int_0^1 (AB)(s,y)C(x,1-s)\,ds
\\&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1A(t,y)B(s,1-t)\,dt\right)C(x,1-s)\,ds
\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^1A(t,y)B(s,1-t)C(x,1-s)\,dt\,ds
\end{align}$$$$
\begin{align}
(A(BC))(x,y) 
&= \int_0^1 A(s,y)(BC)(x,1-s)\,ds
\\&=\int_0^1A(s,y)\left(\int_0^1B(t,1-s)C(x,1-t)\,dt\right)\,ds
\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^1A(s,y)B(t,1-s)C(x,1-t)\,dt\,ds
\\&\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}=\int_0^1\int_0^1A(s,y)B(t,1-s)C(x,1-t)\,ds\,dt
\\&\stackrel{s\leftrightarrow t}=\int_0^1\int_0^1A(t,y)B(s,1-t)C(x,1-s)\,dt\,ds
\\&= ((AB)C)(x,y)
\end{align}
$$